# How can I specify 2 random factors in nlme?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme

I am working with a filed experiment, where we tested the effect of a molecule at three dosages on the maize grain yield. the experiment was conducted for 2 consecutive years and in 2 different soils. I want to test with an ANOVA the effect of the dosage on the yield, considering both the year and the soil as random factor. I generally use nlme with lme function on R studio. I started analyzing with the year as random factor only using this script:

```
model<-lme(yield~dosage, random=~1|year, data=mydata)
```

How can I add another random factor (random=~1|soil), in the same model?

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible with crossed random effects. With nested random effects the code would go model<-lme(yield~dosage, random=list(year=~1, soil=~1, data=mydata), but I think you don't want that - it would nest the random effect of soil within each year. Consider using lmer from lme4, with that it's easy to specify many crossed random effects. You get p-values for a lmer object via lmerTest package.

Comment: forgot a parenthesis from the code, obviously model<-lme(yield~dosage,random=list(year=~1, soil=~1), data=mydata)